# Python - Multiprocessing of multiple variable length iterators

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having trouble identifying how to iterate over two unequal length lists in Python using multiprocessing.  I basically want each value in each list to be computed against each other which I have been accomplishing in a nested loop.  What I am finding is that the routine runs through each list sequentially and then terminates after the shortest list has been iterated through (this does make sense).  I have to assume there is a way to get this to work.  Thx in advance for any guidance.

```
def run_test(short, long):
    print(short)
    print(long)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    short_value = [1,2,3]
    long_value = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
    args = [short_value, long_value]
    all_data=zip(short_value,long_value)
    data=list(all_data)
    with Pool(1) as p:
        p.starmap(run_test, zip(short_value, long_value))
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

> 1  4 2 5 3 6

(never sees 7, 8, and 9 in the longer list)

Comment: Why Pool(1)?  You are not “multiprocessing “ with only one process.

Comment: 7,8,9 not seen because zip generates for the length of the short list.

Comment: You can ignore the Pool(1)…just did that during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute each value in one list against each value in another list, you'll need to compute the Cartesian product of the two lists. You can use `itertools.product` to generate all possible pairs, and then pass these pairs to the `run_test` function using multiprocessing. Following is the modified code:

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_test(short, long):
    print(f'{short} {long}') # Printed on the same line for clarity

if __name__ == '__main__':
    short_value = [1, 2, 3]
    long_value = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    # Generate all possible pairs (Cartesian product) from the two lists
    all_pairs = list(product(short_value, long_value))

    with Pool(1) as p:
        p.starmap(run_test, all_pairs)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

Now, the code will iterate over all possible pairs of values from both lists, and the output will include pairs with values 7, 8, and 9 from the larger list.

Answer (score 0):

`Itertools.product()` works.

```
itertools.product() 

def run_test(args):
    print(args)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    paramlist = list(itertools.product([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8,9]))
    with Pool(1) as p:
        p.map(run_test, paramlist)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

Results:

```
(1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) (1, 9) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6) (2, 7) (2, 8) (2, 9) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6) (3, 7) (3, 8) (3, 9)
```